# Upgrade Rails App From 1.2.3 to 5.0.0.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, migrate, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an app that is running on Rails 1.2.3 created in 2009. Now I want to Upgrade to latest rails version Rails 5.0.0.rc1. I require the git commits made on app to persist with the app, this might not be possible if I am going with re-writing the whole app. What will be the best approch to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is a long long way from the current version!

**Best way** - rewrite your application

**Long way** - follow the change log from the very bottom of the page to the very top http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/

Answer (score 0):

Yiiiip. Best thing to do is just re-write your app, mate. It'll pretty much end up being a total re-write anyway.